Ionic, how to close in-app browser in android.(capacitor/browser)
I am using capacitor/browser. and in document, it says browser.close() works on only web, ios.
Then how can i close browser in android??
Browser.open({ url: 'https://~~' });

setTimeout(() => {
  Browser.close();
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}, 200);

Here is my code, and it works on only web and ios.
i tried applistener, and httpclient.get('url').

You can check one of this gist: https://gist.github.com/im182cm/2c7723d42b2d7091af6c493b97b732b7. Also there is also a support added in here: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/pull/1972, but I am not sure about the release.
